# Why does jQuery Fading Effect not work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a slideshow on my website and I want the transitions of the slides to have a fading animation. For that I used jQuery with the fadeIn and fadeOut commands. I actually have two questions:

1. The animation does work, however not properly; when I click to the next image, it has the normal, hard change and then the new image is fading out and in again instead of one fading out and the other one fading in. Why is that and how can that be corrected?
2. The images are only fading in and out when i click the arrows, not when the slideshow is automatically going through the images with my interval of 5 seconds. I tried to integrate the effect with a change-event (when the image is changing the animation should appear) but that doesn't work. Do I have to use another eventhandler oder is there a whole other way?

I couldn't find anything helpful on Google to these questions so I'd be very grateful if someone could help me with this, since I'm also very new to JavaScript and need it for a university project. Thank you! :)

```js
var DiashowBilder = new Array("Bilder/1.jpeg", "Bilder/2.jpeg", "Bilder/3.jpeg", "Bilder/4.jpeg", "Bilder/5.jpeg", "Bilder/6.jpeg", "Bilder/7.jpeg", "Bilder/8.jpeg", "Bilder/9.jpeg", "Bilder/10.jpeg");  
var index = 0;

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#animation").click(function() {
    jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeOut(400, function() {
      diashow();
      jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeIn(400);
    });
  })
  jQuery("#animation").change(function() {
    jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeOut(400, function() {
      diashow();
      jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeIn(400);
    });
  })
  jQuery("#next").click(function() {
    jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeOut(400, function() {
      diashow();
      jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeIn(400);
    });
  })
  jQuery("#previous").click(function() {
    jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeOut(400, function() {
      diashow();
      jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeIn(400);
    });
  })
});

function nextIMG(n) {
    diashow(index += n);
    document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[index].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[index -n].classList.remove("active");
    if (index == DiashowBilder.length) {
        index = 0;
        document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[10].classList.remove("active");
    }
    if (index < 0) {
        index = DiashowBilder.length -1;
    }
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    diashow(index = n);
    dot[index].classList.add("active")
}

function diashow() {
    document.getElementById("Vorschaubild").src = DiashowBilder[index];
    if (index == DiashowBilder.length) {
        index = 0;
    }
    if (index < 0) {
        index = DiashowBilder.length -1;
    }
}
diashow();
function automatischWeiterschalten() {
    nextIMG(1);
}
setInterval(automatischWeiterschalten, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="prev" onclick="nextIMG(-1)" id="previous">&#10094;</a>
<div id="animation">
  <img id="Vorschaubild" />
  <br/><br/>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)" id="dot1"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)" id="dot2"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)" id="dot3"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)" id="dot4"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)" id="dot5"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)" id="dot6"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)" id="dot7"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)" id="dot8"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)" id="dot9"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)" id="dot10"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="next" onclick="nextIMG(1)" id="next">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you take some time to update the question to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?  We don't know what `nextIMG` is or what `diashow` is, what other code you might be using for your "slideshow", etc.  But the description suggests that there's a lot more to this than what you're showing us.  Just providing partial code and saying "it doesn't work" isn't really answerable.

Comment: For such requirements, Try to use the CSS for effects and use Jquery to simply add the class on it. However you need to explain question for people to understand it.

Comment: Sorry I just edited it I hope it's enough now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main reason why your code won't work as desired is the fact, that the animation is completely unrelated to the update of the src property. The update must happen within the fade function, otherwise this will never be synchronized  and work properly.

I updated your code a little bit and moved the animation to the correct location. (And using images which are actually displayed)
The code is still not 100% working, but it will allow you to continue your development.

Things to keep in mind:

- What happens if you go back when you are at index 0
- What happens if the interval image triggers during the 800ms transition you manually started (Maybe consider stopping the interval in this case and restarting it after the transition finished)
- Why do you split your logic into nextIMG and diashow. Wouldn't it be better to remove the `"active"` after the fade out and then add the new `"active"` after the fade in?

```js
var DiashowBilder = new Array("https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e4e/circulate-abstract-1562332.jpg", "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/4ea/abstract-building-1226559.jpg", "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/e4e/circulate-abstract-1562332.jpg", "https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/5ae/summer-holiday-1188633.jpg");  
var index = 0;

jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#animation").click(function() {
    nextIMG(1);
  })
  jQuery("#next").click(function() {
    nextIMG(-1);
  })
  jQuery("#previous").click(function() {
    nextIMG(1);
  })
});

function nextIMG(n) {
    diashow(index += n);
    document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[index].classList.add("active");
    document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[index -n].classList.remove("active");
    if (index == DiashowBilder.length) {
        index = 0;
        document.getElementsByClassName("dot")[10].classList.remove("active");
    }
    if (index < 0) {
        index = DiashowBilder.length -1;
    }
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    diashow(index = n);
    dot[index].classList.add("active")
}

function diashow() {
    jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeOut(400, function() {
      document.getElementById("Vorschaubild").src = DiashowBilder[index];
      if (index == DiashowBilder.length) {
          index = 0;
      }
      if (index < 0) {
          index = DiashowBilder.length -1;
      }
      jQuery("#Vorschaubild").fadeIn(400);
    });
}
diashow();
function automatischWeiterschalten() {
    nextIMG(1);
}
setInterval(automatischWeiterschalten, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="prev" onclick="nextIMG(-1)" id="previous">&#10094;</a>
<div id="animation">
  <img id="Vorschaubild" />
  <br/><br/>
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)" id="dot1"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)" id="dot2"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)" id="dot3"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)" id="dot4"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)" id="dot5"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(6)" id="dot6"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(7)" id="dot7"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(8)" id="dot8"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(9)" id="dot9"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(10)" id="dot10"></span>
  </div>
</div>

<a class="next" onclick="nextIMG(1)" id="next">&#10095;</a>
```